# Unable to get all folders inside my site libraries root folders and move them to another site

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate

I have  created a scheduled flow which get all lists and libraries from a site >> then loop through the files/folders inside the root folder of each list/library and then move them to a destination site, here what i have so far:-

[image]

so i am doing these actions:-

1. get all lists and libraries:-

[image]

2. Get all files and folders inside the root:-

[image]

but on the "Get file properties" action >> where i want to get the folder/file and pass them to the Move Folder action >> i did not get the outcomes of the "Get file (properties only)" inside the "Get file properties" action.. any advice?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is there any relevant error message? Have you ever thought about using power shell for migration?
https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2017/02/sharepoint-online-copy-files-between-site-collections-using-powershell.html

Comment: @AmyJiang_MSFT no errors but i am not getting the properties as shown in my picture

Comment: @AmyJiang_MSFT Also the customer do not want to pay extra fees to run scheduled azure functions .. so we need this to be done using Power automate